# How to get inflections for a word using Wordnet

Tags: nlp, wordnet

I want to get inflectional forms for a word using Wordnet.

E.g. If the word is `make`, then its inflections are

```
made, makes, making
```

I tried all the options of the `wn` command but I did not get the inflections for a word.

Any idea how to get these?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure wordnet was intended to inflect words. Just found this little writeup about how WordNet(R) makes use of the Morphy algorithm to make a morphological determination of the head term associated with an inflected form https://github.com/jdee/dubsar/wiki/Inflections. I needed some inflection for a project of mine (Python) a little ago and I used https://github.com/pwdyson/inflect.py and https://bitbucket.org/cnu/montylingua3/overview/ (required some hacking, also take a look at the original http://web.media.mit.edu/~hugo/montylingua/)

Comment: Yeah, what's asked for in this question is impossible. WordNet doesn't contain a comprehensive list of inflected forms, nor does it contain any mechanism for generating inflected forms from base forms. A different tool is needed.

Answer (score 1):

This python package LemmInflect provides functions to get all inflections of a word.

Just copy their examples here:

```
> from lemminflect import getInflection, getAllInflections, getAllInflectionsOOV
> getInflection('watch', tag='VBD')
('watched',)

> getAllInflections('watch')
{'NN': ('watch',), 'NNS': ('watches', 'watch'), 'VB': ('watch',), 'VBD': ('watched',), 'VBG': ('watching',), 'VBZ': ('watches',),  'VBP': ('watch',)}

> getAllInflections('watch', upos='VERB')
{'VB': ('watch',), 'VBP': ('watch',), 'VBD': ('watched',), 'VBG': ('watching',), 'VBZ': ('watches',)}

> getAllInflectionsOOV('xxwatch', upos='NOUN')
{'NN': ('xxwatch',), 'NNS': ('xxwatches',)}
```

Check out https://lemminflect.readthedocs.io/en/latest/inflections/ for more details.