# Extract different emotions for words Affect WordNet

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I'm trying to use Affect WordNet to use the different emotions that are implemented within, like: anger, dislike, fear negative-fear, joy, sad etc.

I found a code sample for that on the library: https://github.com/clemtoy/WNAffect

```
from wnaffect import WNAffect
import nltk
nltk.download('dict')

wna = WNAffect('wordnet-1.6/', 'wn-domains-3.2/')
emo = wna.get_emotion('angry', 'JJ')

print(emo)
```

I tested it and I got this error:

> Resource dict not found.   Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain
>   the resource:
>
> import nltk nltk.download('dict')

I tried to use NLTK downloader to download it, but nothing there !
[image]

A similar question was asked before here: [Extract “emotion words” / affect words from english corpus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653815/how-to-get-inflections-for-a-word-using-wordnet) 
but they solved it by using sentiwordNet to retrieve the negative and the positive scores !

Comment: from  nltk.corpus import WordNetCorpusReader

Comment: The same error ..

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27943396/using-wn-affect-to-detect-emotion-mood-of-a-string ?

Comment: there is no solution provided!

Comment: There's no existing easy solution to map wn1.6 to 3.0. So is highly possible that wnaffect wont make it into nltk-abl API like sentiment wordnet